# How do I connect two android devices with a central server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, webserver

I'd like to know how a central server works in connecting two devices. I'm assuming that when the device application starts up, it should register its IP address and other pertinent information (username) with the server. When it wants to connect to another device, it should look to find the address of another device on the server, maybe with a get request. Then set up a to connect to a socket. If the device application closes, it should unregister from the server. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much correct.

Because one or both devices are probably behind firewalls (including NAT), you have to assume they won't actually be able to connect directly to each other, so it won't be as simple as opening a socket to the other device once you find out its registered address. You will either have to try firewall-traversal techniques (which will usually be successful with UDP but not with TCP) or have a helper that isn't behind a firewall (which could be the same as the registration server or something else) carry all the data between the devices that wish to communicate.

Also, you will want to have the registration server time out registrations and the clients periodically refresh them, because clients won't always have a chance to deregister themselves on the server when they terminate or lose access to the network.

Comment: Assuming I did what you explain, how would I make the central server forward whatever is communicated to the other device? In my example, device 1 acquires device 2's IP from the central server, connects to it through a socket and streams tcp video, audio, file etc. to it. If it's using the server as an intermediary, how often does it have to poll it for new, ex., video frames?

Comment: If direct communication between the endpoints is not in use then the server could forward the traffic by naively `write()`ing to one client a copy or everything is `read()`s from the other and vice versa. As for your second question about how to control the streaming rate, that depends on your protocol and whether you are using TCP or UDP. If it's live content than the streaming rate is pretty much predetermined. If you're using TCP, TCP does flow control for you. If you're using UDP for non-live content, you're on your own and you have to implement a flow control mechanism the hard way.