# Communication between two clients

Tags: sockets, pthreads, ipc, rpc

Hello I have cli/server application where I need communication setup between 2 clients.
Example:

```
Cli A connects to server->serverThreadA
Cli B connects to server->serverThreadB
cli C connects to server->serverThreadC
...etc.
```

Then let's say I want Cli A to setup connection with Cli C.

Would I than have to communicate with main thread(Server) and have it request
Cli C to setup a connection for me to connect to and than main thread passes the
address/port info to me?

Would I want to use RPC? or sockets?

I am wondering what would be the best way to do this.

Thanks for any guidance/suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to write chat server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect two android devices with a central server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506487/how-do-i-connect-two-android-devices-with-a-central-server)

Comment: My question is more regarding best possible setup for the above.  I can either communicate via the Server(main thread) or have the Clients setup to directly communicate with each other.  So we have CliA->Server->CliC or CliA->CliC (this initially requires communication between clients through Server so that it can pass connectivity info to each client).  I am wondering which is a better design.  With one I can use IPC throughout the other I will work with network sockets to establish direct communication between both clients.